# Comparison error with Visual Studio 16.11.27 in C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, optimization, visual-c++, compilation

The following code is having some very weird behavior when (not) entering in the second `if` block when compiling with Visual Studio 2019 16.11.27 (latest version) in Release build. Does it has any error?

The expected output is 2, but it does only occurs in Debug build.

The input should be "2 0 1".

```cpp
// ConsoleApplication1.cpp : This file contains the 'main' function. Program execution begins and ends there.
//
​
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
​
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

  if (argc!=4)
  {
    printf("Call with 2 0 1 as argument") ;
    return 1;
  } 
  // planeprev=2 cplane=0 cplane_id=1
  int ninfl = 0;
  int planeprev = std::stoi(argv[1]);
  int cplane = std::stoi(argv[2]);
  int cplane_id = std::stoi(argv[3]);
  std::cout << "PP=" << planeprev << " CP=" << cplane << " CPID=" << cplane_id << std::endl;
  if (cplane_id > planeprev && cplane_id < cplane)
  {
    ninfl = 2;
  }
  else if (cplane_id < planeprev && cplane_id > cplane)
  {
    ninfl = 2;
  }
  else if ((cplane == cplane_id && cplane > planeprev) ||
    (planeprev == cplane_id && cplane < planeprev))
  {
    ninfl = 1;
  }
  else if ((cplane == cplane_id && cplane < planeprev) ||
    (planeprev == cplane_id && cplane > planeprev))
  {
    ninfl = 1;
  }
​
  if(ninfl!=2)
  printf("ERROR OUTPUT! \n");
  else
  printf("CORRECT OUTPUT\n");
}
```

Comment: You should provide an example of your command-line input that fails since this program requires it. Also, if you really feel it's specific to a particular version of the compiler you can try out https://godbolt.org/ although that doesn't seem likely in this case.

Comment: The input should be "2 0 1"

Comment: Expected is ninfl=2

Comment: Side note: you may have over-minimized simplifying the code in the question, but if not, you should never use `argv` unless you've first checked `argc` to make sure it's safe.

Comment: Maybe you did not add the command line parameters in Release mode. Remember the configuration settings (including the command line arguments used) for Debug and Release are separate.

Comment: I did use the default Release mode in Visual Studio IDE. I did not use the command line interface.

Comment: Recommendation: Add the erroneous output to the question so folks have some idea where the program winds up. Could be a good hint or two in that for someone who knows the ins-and-outs of cl.

Comment: ***I did use the default Release mode in Visual Studio IDE. I did not use the command line interface.*** Your code requires that you edit the `Project Properties->Debugging->Command Line Arguments`  setting for Release in the Visual Studio 2019 IDE for it to work at all in Release mode.

Comment: Yes, @drescherjm I did this to run Release build with arguments, but you can try running directly the Release executable in CLI too

Comment: I do have Visual Studio 2019 but I don't have this exact version and I can't change my version because of a work dependency (all machines have the same version of msvc installed).

Comment: @drescherjm but what version are you using? It worked as expected? In my tests the version 16.11.20 does work well

Comment: @ViniciusAlmada -- What happens if you hardcoded the values of 2, 0, and 1 into the variables?

Comment: It does say "CORRECT OUTPUT" in Debug and "ERROR OUTPUT!"  in release in my version of VS 2019. And that happens in 32 or 64 bit.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie it works correctly in both versions

Comment: @drescherjm that is my problem, why this happens?

Comment: I don't know. This is odd.

Comment: I just tried with VS 2022, 17.6.4, and it seems to be an issue there also.

Comment: If I put `int planeprev = 2;  int cplane = 0; int cplane_id = 1;` instead it works in release.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I tried in VS2022 too, it worked well. But at my work I must use this VS2019

Comment: @ViniciusAlmada Did you try version 17.6.4 in VS2002?  I did, and I am having the same issue.

Comment: @ViniciusAlmada You may want to open a ticket with Microsoft's Visual C++ people, because it looks like a bug in the optimizer.  It seems it is trying to optimize all of those conditionals, and somehow believing that the second `else if` conditional should be wiped out.  I'm looking for signs of undefined behavior, but I don't see any.

Comment: If you changed the `else if (cplane_id < planeprev && cplane_id > cplane)` to `if (cplane_id < planeprev && cplane_id > cplane)`, then the program works as it should.  Looks like an optimization bug.

Comment: I changed the code to put the code in a function and to use a `TEST_BUG` define (line 33) to make it easy to toggle between command line arguments and variables initialized in the code: [https://gist.github.com/drescherjm/1f2b75af770e2e51f4dce515f15cf5f4](https://gist.github.com/drescherjm/1f2b75af770e2e51f4dce515f15cf5f4) for me it fails in Release with command line arguments and works in when using variables initialized in the code. This is very odd. I don't see any UB in the code.

Comment: @ViniciusAlmada [Report a bug](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/overview/how-to-report-a-problem-with-the-visual-cpp-toolset?view=msvc-170), and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-report-a-problem-with-visual-studio?view=vs-2022)

Comment: @ViniciusAlmada -- Once you create the ticket, you should report the ticket number back here so others can track it.

Comment: @drescherjm Seems I've managed to simplify it even further, eliminating the command line altogether: try https://godbolt.org/z/vf9Woo981 (in VS2019).

Comment: Thanks, I suspected that it was something with stoi()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I posted in MSVC forum community at [this link](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/code-flow-not-entering-in-if-else-condit/10409770). It is an optimization bug.

They did answer:

> A fix for this issue has been internally implemented and is being prepared for release. We’ll update you once it becomes available for download.

Comment: Please consider accepting it as an answer to change this thread's status to Answered.  It will also help others to solve the similar issue.